# Is there an approval database module for Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am looking for a module that will help me build an Approval Database. My thought is having a members only site, say 5 different departments (which each member will belong to one of the 5 departments). Have all departments having a say in a project. Each department would approve or reject a version (reject meaning there are changes needed). Once every department approves or rejects, then the project will be approved (if approvals for all departments), or ready and wait for version 2 or 3 or 4 and so on (if there are rejections and issues for following versions). If rejected, there would be a form where the rejecting department could list the issues that need addressed. Once the issues were fixed, a member could click a "complete" button from a radio button or select list. If a department approved in a previous version, they would have some kind of carryover approval where they would not have to approve every time there was a new version. Does anyone know of a module that would point me in the right direction or would have some sort of idea how to achieve this?
thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Drupal core **Revisions** and [Workflow](https://drupal.org/project/workflow) modules (See also the *Related Modules* on the bootom right page of the Workflow module to get some alternatives). The 5 departments can be a 5 user **Roles** and the permissions can be handled by [Field_permissions](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module. Issues can be **Comments** below each project. Of course, each Project can (and should) be a **Node**.

In any case, the functionality you describe needs a good knowledge of Drupal and can be done using several modules and approaches.